# How to change Tensor format to channels first in Tensorflow js?

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, computer-vision, reshape, tensorflow.js

I'm new to Computer Vision model structure, and I'm using Tensorflow for Node JS `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` to make some models detect some objects. With Mobilenet and Resnet SSD, the models are using the `Channels Last` format, so when I create a Tensor with `tf.node.decodeImage` the format is by default `Channels Last`, like `shape: [1, 1200, 1200, 3]` for 3 channels, and the predictions data work great, able to recognize objects.

But  model from Pytorch, converted to ONNX, then to Protobuf PB format, the `saved_model.pb` has the `Channels First` format, like `shape: [1, 3, 1200, 1200]`.

Now I need to create Tensor from image but with `Channels First` format. I found many exemple of creating `conv1d, conv2d` specifying the format `dataFormat='channelsFirst'`. But I don't know how to apply it to an image data. Here is the API https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#layers.conv2d .

Here is the Tensor codes:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
let imgTensor = tf.node.decodeImage(new Uint8Array(subBuffer), 3);
imgTensor = imgTensor.cast('float32').div(255);
imgTensor = imgTensor.expandDims(0); // to add the most left axis of size 1
console.log('tensor', imgTensor);
```

This gives me a shape with channels last that is not compatible with the Model shape with channels first:

```
tensor Tensor {
  kept: false,
  isDisposedInternal: false,
  shape: [ 1, 1200, 1200, 3 ],
  dtype: 'float32',
  size: 4320000,
  strides: [ 4320000, 3600, 3 ],
  dataId: {},
  id: 7,
  rankType: '4',
  scopeId: 4
}
```

I know of `tf.shape`, but it reshapes without converting to channels first, and the result seems useless in predictions results. Don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```js
const nchw = tf.transpose(nhwc, [0, 3, 1, 2]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that is the permute equivalent in Python, cool.